# JFrame GUI addition method not working

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Okay I have a GUI that takes text input (say 10) and then you can check box what you want to add to that initial amount (four choices 10, 20, 50, 100). After that I am trying to display the sum of the items in another text frame.

```
int firstMuffler = Integer.parseInt(inputMufflers.getText());
    int firstTire = Integer.parseInt(inputTires.getText());
    int firstBreaks = Integer.parseInt(inputBreaks.getText());
    int firstMirrors = Integer.parseInt(inputMirrors.getText());
    if (Muf10.isSelected()){
        FinalStockMuf.setText(String.valueOf(firstMuffler + 10)); 
    }
    else if (Muf20.isSelected()){
        FinalStockMuf.setText(String.valueOf(firstMuffler + 20));
    }
    else if (Muf50.isSelected()){
        FinalStockMuf.setText(String.valueOf(firstMuffler + 50));
    }
    else if (Muf100.isSelected()){
        FinalStockMuf.setText(String.valueOf(firstMuffler + 100));
    }
    else if (T10.isSelected()){
        FinalStockT.setText(String.valueOf(firstTire + 10));
    }
    else if (T20.isSelected()){
        FinalStockT.setText(String.valueOf(firstTire + 20));
    }
    else if (T50.isSelected()){
        FinalStockT.setText(String.valueOf(firstTire + 50));
    }
    else if (T100.isSelected()){
        FinalStockT.setText(String.valueOf(firstTire + 100));
    }
    else if (B10.isSelected()){
        FinalStockB.setText(String.valueOf(firstBreaks + 10));
    }
    else if (B20.isSelected()){
        FinalStockB.setText(String.valueOf(firstBreaks + 20));
    }
    else if (B50.isSelected()){
        FinalStockB.setText(String.valueOf(firstBreaks + 50));
    }
    else if (B100.isSelected()){
        FinalStockB.setText(String.valueOf(firstBreaks + 100));
    }
    else if (M10.isSelected()){
        FinalStockM.setText(String.valueOf(firstMirrors + 10));
    }
    else if (M20.isSelected()){
        FinalStockM.setText(String.valueOf(firstMirrors+ 20));
    }
    else if (M50.isSelected()){
        FinalStockM.setText(String.valueOf(firstMirrors + 50));
    }
    else if (M100.isSelected()){
        FinalStockM.setText(String.valueOf(firstMirrors + 100));
    }else{

    }
```

This is what I have, I can't figure out what is making it not work. Because it only outputs the `FinalStockMuf` text box and the rest don't work. I also have to fill everything out to make it work, like zeros.

Note: `Muf10`, `T10`, etc. Are the check boxes with those values.
`firstTire`, `firstMug`, etc. Is the first price that is input, without any check boxes checked.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Here are two links to download it. It only has the one method in the source code.  http://speedy.sh/DGRnu/StockManagerGUI.form
http://speedy.sh/vRSNQ/StockManagerGUI.java

Comment: *"Here are two links to download it."*  Two points: 1) An MCVE as linked by @MadProgrammer is only ever a single source file (though that source file might contain more than one class). 2) If you can produce an MCVE, post it here as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30179782/edit).  Some of us cannot follow external links, most of the rest of us refuse to.

Comment: Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `else if` ladder, you need to remember that only one option, which meets the requirements, is executed. In your example, you implemented code responsible for collecting and inserting data from/to multiple objects in one else if ladder. In effect, first option which satisfied condition worked, and rest was ignored. Therefore, you should change your code like this:

```
    if (Muf10.isSelected()){
        FinalStockMuf.setText(String.valueOf(firstMuffler + 10));
    }
    else if (Muf20.isSelected()){
        FinalStockMuf.setText(String.valueOf(firstMuffler + 20));
    }
    else if (Muf50.isSelected()){
        FinalStockMuf.setText(String.valueOf(firstMuffler + 50));
    }
    else if (Muf100.isSelected()){
        FinalStockMuf.setText(String.valueOf(firstMuffler + 100));
    } 

    //break and beginning of new else if structure,

    if (T10.isSelected()){
        FinalStockT.setText(String.valueOf(firstTire + 10));
    }
    else if (T20.isSelected()){
        FinalStockT.setText(String.valueOf(firstTire + 20));
    }
    else if (T50.isSelected()){
        FinalStockT.setText(String.valueOf(firstTire + 50));
    }
    else if (T100.isSelected()){
        FinalStockT.setText(String.valueOf(firstTire + 100));
    }

    //break and beginning of new else if structure,

    if (B10.isSelected()){
        FinalStockB.setText(String.valueOf(firstBreaks + 10));
    }
    else if (B20.isSelected()){
        FinalStockB.setText(String.valueOf(firstBreaks + 20));
    }
    else if (B50.isSelected()){
        FinalStockB.setText(String.valueOf(firstBreaks + 50));
    }
    else if (B100.isSelected()){
        FinalStockB.setText(String.valueOf(firstBreaks + 100));
    }

    //break and beginning of new else if structure,

    if (M10.isSelected()){
        FinalStockM.setText(String.valueOf(firstMirrors + 10));
    }
    else if (M20.isSelected()){
        FinalStockM.setText(String.valueOf(firstMirrors+ 20));
    }
    else if (M50.isSelected()){
        FinalStockM.setText(String.valueOf(firstMirrors + 50));
    }
    else if (M100.isSelected()){
        FinalStockM.setText(String.valueOf(firstMirrors + 100));
    }
```

And it should work just fine. 
Next problem is a `NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`, thrown when any input text field is empty. To solve that I would use:

```
int firstMuffler = (!inputMufflers.getText().equals("")) ? Integer.parseInt(inputMufflers.getText()) : 0;
```

...and similar solution for every next `JTextField`. This code checks if `JTextField` is empty, and if it is, it gives a 0 value to `firstMuffler`. However it doesn't fill `JTextField` with '0'.

To fill output `JTextField` with not modified value of stock or input and output JTextField with '0' if there was no input, it is enough to add for example:

```
    }else if(inputMufflers.getText().equals("")){
        inputMufflers.setText("0");
        FinalStockMuf.setText("0");
    }else{
        FinalStockMuf.setText(inputMufflers.getText());
    }
```

to the end of every `else if` part.
I hope you will find my answer useful.